# How to set what is new in google play developer console

Tags: android, publishing

I am new to android developer console. I already have added an app in the play store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fyrweel.flashbee). But when I tried to release an update, I couldn't figure out how to set the "What is New in Version". So I did it in the app description itself. I am going to release another major update. At least now I need to set the "What is New" properly. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just played your [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fyrweel.flashbee) Its a nice one.Just loved it :) Addictive type of a game :) Congratz .Keep going :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you upload the update apk, there will be a section where you can fill in the "What's new" before you confirm the publishing of your update.

Comment: I can't figure out how to update the "What's new" section after the fact, like without uploading a new apk

Answer (score 0):

In APK section, click on the latest APK where you want to add this section. That will open a pop-up showing the details regarding that APK. Scroll down to find the "What is new" section. You can edit this section